# Como repetir um conteúdo em várias páginas estáticas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dry

A questão é a seguinte, eu tenho apenas arquivos estáticos .HTML e estou procurando uma forma simples de criar os blocos apenas uma vez utilizando apenas o **client side**.

A idéia é respeitar o DRY, existe alguma forma de fazer isso diretamente com JavaScript ou o jQuery?

Comment: Porque não gravas o codigo.js e o importas nas páginas?

Comment: @Miguel, pode me dar um exemplo simples de como voce importaria?

Comment: <script src="caminho/para/o/teu/codigo.js"></script>, em baixo no html, antes de fechares a tag `<body></body>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

#### Usando o [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery

Exemplo: carregar o conteúdo de **header.html** para a div com id `header`.

```
$("#header").load("public/header.html");
```

Comment: sabe me dizer a questão de performance, se influencia muito?

Comment: Vai depender de alguns fatores, possivelmente carregar tudo direto é (minimamente) mais performático, pelo menos em situações normais e também, quase sempre esse ganho de performance é imperceptível. Eu posso te garantir que o ganho em performance em **não utilizar** este tipo de recurso não compensa a perda de tempo e a dor de cabeça que vai ser ter que editar muitos arquivos toda vez que for precisar de uma alteração, ainda mais se o site tiver muitas páginas. Você precisa avaliar uma maneira satisfatória, mesmo que eu soubesse te responder com certeza qual o mais performático, você [+]

Comment: [+] vai precisar avaliar o caso diante do seu escopo. (PS: Tou saindo agora. Qualquer dúvida, deixa um comentário aí que quando eu voltar respondo)

Comment: Só complementando, você pode tanto definir o carregamento de páginas inteiras ou apenas um bloco específico, ex: uma div, uma tabela etc. Uma forma de fazer isso: `$("#nome-da-div").load("public/header.html #nome-da-div");`.